# Deciding database need

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I have small .net application which I sell.
I was using Access as database but I think it's not flexible and fast enough. Also I'm planning to enable network database access so I need suggestions which database system to move.

My program is a shop sales organizer and I record every sale on a shop. I need customer, stock, sale records in the database. Some clients make 10k sales and about 100k products in a month.

**EDIT:**

Also the database system must be easy to manage and easy to backup.

Comment: You mention the database, but what are you using for things like forms and reports?

Comment: I don't use Access reports. Just tables and views. I use Crystal Reports. Also I'm using Microsoft DAO 3.6.

Comment: So no forms or forms code is used then?

Comment: I'm not using Access forms, if you're asking this. My application is Winforms and Vb.Net.

Comment: One reason to avoid Jet/ACE for the data store would be if you want to support networking across WiFi. That just doesn't work with a Jet/ACE back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that your current configuration using an Access file isn't sufficient. Beware of all the Access horror stories that usually start with, "I haven't used Access since 2.0, but I recall some problem. with, blah, blah, blah." About as bad as judging Windows 7 because of some crash you experienced with Win95.

Seems like a noticable performance problem by your clients with larger datasets would have been recognized or your product is experiencing too many errors that you attribute to the data file. Just seems like there would be other features and functionality that clients would appreciate a lot more over premature scaling.

You mentioned SQL Server CE. It can handle up to 4 gigs of data just like Express. Both can be deployed with your installation package. CE's installation is much smaller: 1.8mb v 197mb. Both offer Transact-SQL, but CE lacks Procedural T-SQL as well as stored proc, views and triggers (A big reason not to use it IMO.). Express is server based and has more service features. It's probably more secure by denying users direct access to the data files and to make things easier offers Role-based security. CE files are document safe since they have no code and you could create your own file extension that is specific to your application. I'm guessing your app runs most of the time on the installed machines so having the over-head of SQL Express service running all the time may or may not be a problem. Retail shops don't seem to use high-performance hardware. You may want something lighter.

No conversion is perfect. Depending on how you've developed your application, sticking with a MS product may be easier. It all depends.

Answer (score 3):

If you want zero configuration, I'd recommend the embedded database [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is , small, efficient, reliable, and free.

You don't have to go through the trouble of setting up a db server on the users machine and as long as you don't have tons of traffic, works well in a networks setup.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL` is a great choice. And I believe newer versions (finally) allow for strictly enforced foreign keys. I have used this on many occasions.

If you will be redistributing your system (so users can set up their own sales shop), I highly recommend `sqlite`. It's fast, free, and growing in popularity all the time. There are now APIs for all major programming languages. Also, there are ways to run it on a webserver, if that's a consideration for your project.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is fast, small, efficient, reliable, and free.  I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you feel Access is not flexible or fast enough?  Access also works well with multiple users on a network.

Note that there is a difference between the database engine portion of Access and the UI portion of Access which allows you to create queries, forms, reports, nacros and VBA code.  Many of the posters here have only mentioned the database engine portion in their reply.

Comment: Maybe you're incompetent. If so, changing database engines won't address the underlying problem.

Comment: I asked this question because It seems I'm going to have problems with access. About data amounts. Also I'll need other clients for same database and Access is not enough. It's not scalable and cannot be used remotely.

Comment: Have you tested hwo much Access slows down?    Why do you think you feel you will have problems?  What kind of volumnts of transactions?   Scalable depends on the volumes of users.   Now remotely on less than LAN speeds, yes, that's a problem.  But, otherwise, it shure sounds like you've already made up your mind that you're going to have problems.

Comment: Gioven that we now know a bit more about your situation and that you're only use Access database files for data storage then I'd suggest using SQL Server Express which is free for database sizes up to 4 Gb. (I think.)

Comment: With the amount of data mentioned, Access will only slow down if you're doing absolutely everything COMPLETELY WRONG. Tony, you and I have both had Access apps with Jet/ACE back ends with 100s of thousands of records in both tables, and performance was fine.

Comment: David, well, things were getting a bit wonky with one report with the transactiosn file had about 700k records in it.  They did upsize a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

what's not flexible, the screens, reports, procedures?.. How many: concurrent users?.. transactions per second? Don't forget that you can use SQL engine with access vs. jet, and the best of feature of access is the integration with excel, word and other modules. for access features visit:
 [link text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/access-2010-features-and-benefits-HA101809011.aspx) http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/access-2010-features-and-benefits-HA101809011.aspx